# The SonarScanner for MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am getting Error after Integrating SonarQube

Unpacking https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-msbuild/releases/download/5.5.3.43281/sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.5.3.43281-net46.zip to C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\sonarqube on Jenkins
[DevOpsAPI] $ C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\sonarqube\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:88e6e2b1-f890-4d12-b867-6dc4cc19d853 /n:DevOpsAPI /v: /d:sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/ ********
SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.5.3
Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
06:51:54.572  Updating build integration targets...
06:51:58.311  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
06:52:13.667  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for cs...
06:52:13.668  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...
06:52:17.715  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for vbnet...
06:52:17.715  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...
06:52:18.209  Pre-processing succeeded.
[DevOpsAPI] $ C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\sonarqube\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end ********
SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.5.3
Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Post-processing started.
06:52:23.746  The SonarScanner for MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
Possible causes:

1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0.25420.1 and higher are supported.
3. The begin, build and end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
4. None of the analyzed projects have a valid ProjectGuid and you have not used a solution (.sln)
   06:52:23.747  Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete the analysis.
   06:52:23.773  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
   WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeed?
   ERROR: Execution of SonarScanner for MSBuild failed (exit code 1)
   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket Build is still running
   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket Using S3 profile: mosesalfred-1
   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=mosesalfred-1, file=DevOps.zip region=ap-south-1, will be uploaded from slave=false managed=false , server encryption false
   Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Are you calling MSBuild to build the solution between the begin and end steps?
If so, please share the logs for the build step.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the tasks in the following order:

[image]